# Impact of POS and Shrading on tx costs?

Tags: gas, proof-of-stake, casper

How transaction fees will be affected after implementation of [Casper protocol](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/ethereum-casper/)?

Comment: https://blockgeeks.com/guides/ethereum-casper/